# Cocoa: JSON returned integer value is id not an int, how to type cast into integer?

Tags: json, cocoa

I have a simple json file as:

```
{
             "id": 1,
             "url": "someUrl",
            "question": "What is the name?",
        "answer": [
            {
                "a": {
                    "text": "Back to the A",
                    "status": 0
                }
            }
}
```

I was able to parse all these data into my xcode project with the following code:

```
NSData* myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebsite.net/json/myValidjson.json"]
                        ];
    NSDictionary* json = nil;
    if (myData) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:myData
                options:kNilOptions
                error:nil];
    }
```

After this, the value of the following code:

```
json[@"movies"][0][@"answer"][0][@"a"][@"status"];
```

is 0, and I am fine up to this point.

Now when I tried to compare like:

```
if (json[@"movies"][0][@"answer"][0][@"a"][@"status"] == 0) {
    NSLog("Value is Equal.");
}
```

This caparison is supposed to be true because the value of json[@"movies"][0][@"answer"][0][@"a"][@"status"] is 0 but infact its an id, not an integer. So, the comparison outputs false.

Why am I getting this result? What will be the solution for this so that I can get that "IF" condition to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that you can store objects only in `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`, you can't directly put or get an integer like that. That's what the `NSNumber` class was invented for. When parsing JSON, the parser, whenever it encounters a number, instantiates an `NSNumber` with the proper value. If you expect an integer, you can do what you want like this:

```
if ([json[@"movies"][0][@"answer"][0][@"a"][@"status"] intValue] == 0)
```

Or compare the objects directly:

```
if ([json[@"movies"][0][@"answer"][0][@"a"][@"status"] isEqual:@0])
```

Comment: awesome H2CO3 !!! I am so stupid, I knew it but forgot about intValue. Worked for me, thank you so much for reminding me this.

Comment: @jeewan The only thing to keep in mind is that only objects can go into a dictionary, no primitives. And from there, everything is logical and easy :)

Comment: yeah, you are right H2CO3. You saved my day, thanks. I will be careful from now :-)